# How to list all domains in forest?

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, php-5.3, adldap

In *Active Directory Users And Computers* it is easy to just select *Find* =>*Entire Directory* to search a username.

If I don't feed this API ([PHP AD LDAP](http://adldap.sourceforge.net/wiki/doku.php?id=documentation_folder_functions) 4.04) the correct `account_suffix`,`base_dn`,`domain_controllers` it will not return *ANY* information on the user account when I do `$ad->user()->infoCollection($username,array('*'));`

I am able to

```
$ad->findBaseDn();
```

From this, I am able to deduce the current domain my user account is part of...

How would I discover **ALL** domains in the forest that I belong to? ... or is there any easy way to top level query without specifying all this information in a loop through manual input?

If you are familiar with Powershell Active Directory, something like

```
$var = Get-AdForest
$var.Domains
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ldapSearch with a base of:
CN=Partitions,CN=Configuration,DC=example,DC=com

With an LDAP Filter of:
(nETBIOSName=*)

And Returning the Attribute: nCNames

Will return all the AD Domains within the forest in LDAP Format.

However, how "trusts" are configured may restrict or allow access to these Domains.

-jim

Comment: Is it not rather dnsRoot (yourcompany.local) and name (yourcompany) for domain-name ? nCNames returns DC=yourcompany,DC=local, a domain name is yourcompany.local, which is what dnsRoot returns.

Comment: The filter should be (nETBIOSName=*)

Comment: @StefanSteiger - I mentioned the "Will return all the AD Domains within the forest in LDAP Format" But yes the dnsRoot will return as you said.